# Inequality with an integral of probability v.s. summation of probabilty

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading a proof in probability text and stuck with one line which confusing me.

Suppose $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. real-valued random variables sequences with $E|X_i| = \infty$

By applying the fact: $EX^p = \int_0^\infty p y^{p-1}P(X>y)dy$ if $X \ge 0$ and $p>0$,

we can write 
$$\infty = E|X_i| = E|X_1| = \int_0^\infty P(|X_1|>y)dy \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(|X_1| >n)$$

I can understand the equality part above, but how to get the inequality part? I mean I don't quite understand why the integral is less than or equal to the summation ??

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. For $f(y)=P(|X_1|>y)$.$f(y)$ is monotonically decreasing in $y$. Thus
$$
\int_0^\infty f(y) dy= \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \int_k^{k+1} f(y) dy \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} f(k) dy=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)
$$

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you say more words about your inequality part? I still get confusing why $f(y)$ can be replaced by $f(k)$?

Comment: $f(k)\ge f(y)$ on on interval $[k,k+1]$. because this is probability, when $y$ grows it decreases. So $\int_k^{k+1} f(y) dy \le f(k)\int_k^{k+1} dy=f(k)$

Comment: I got it, Thank you so much ! @Alexander Vigodner .

Comment: The choice of the letter $f$ to mean the function $y\mapsto P(|X_1|\gt y)$ is quite unfortunate.

Comment: And what is so unfortunate in this letter in comparison with any other one? Generic monotonic  function $f$.

Comment: Somehow your comment escaped me (perhaps use @). Indeed choosing $f$ is most unfortunate for a (complementary) CDF since nearly everybody uses small letters for PDFs and capital letters for CDFs.